# Put this in the form $y = mx +c$

Tags: graphing-functions

I need this equation in the $y = mx + c$ form, where $k$ is the slope.

I might need to take natural logarithms, but I am not sure?

$${C} = \{{1 - e^{-kt}}\} {A}$$

Comment: There is no $x$ or $y$ in your formula, so how can we express it in the form you wish.  Moreover, if $t$ is the variable of interest (is it?), then your equation is not linear and cannot be placed in the form you seek.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your math. The top-voted question on [the meta site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions) has a great tutorial.

Comment: Maybe you want $x=t$ but what is $y$?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, if the question is of the form $C=1-Ae^{-kt}$, in which case, taking the $\log$ gets down to,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\log (1-C) &=& \log\left(A e^{-kt}\right) \\
&=& \log A -k t
\end{eqnarray*}

That is, $\log A = k t + \log(1-C) $ and is of the form $y=m t +c$, where $y=\log A, m=k $ and $c=\log(1-C)$.